# lxterminal login shell

Tags: ruby, lxterminal

Hi I'm trying to run rvm on my raspberry pi but keep getting the error rvm is not a function when I use the command in LXTerminal:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

It gives an error saying I should use a login shell. So my question is how can I get a login shell on my raspberry pi?

Comment: What instructions did you follow for setting it up and did you log out and back in?

Comment: I installed with te following command:
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby And I did log in and out

Comment: What happens if you do this first  source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Answer (score 1):

To get a login shell, you need to do `bash -l` or `/bin/bash --login` after you start the terminal.